# Grails 3: what is replacement for eventCreateWarStart in _Events.groovy

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I am migrating a plugin from Grails 2.4 to Grails 3. I am facing to the following issue.

I tried to use `eventCreateWarStart` in `_Events.groovy`. Like we used to compile widgetset in our plugin's [_Events.groovy file](https://github.com/ondrej-kvasnovsky/grails-vaadin-plugin/blob/master/grails-vaadin7-plugin/scripts/_Events.groovy). But it seems this approach is not allowed in Grails 3.

I went through the specification and I have not found what is the replacement. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general you cannot use concepts from the old build 2.x build system and have to instead write a Gradle plugin.

For example your requirements sound very similar to the asset pipeline plugin which modifiers Gradle's `war` task to include compiled static assets (see https://github.com/bertramdev/asset-pipeline-core/blob/master/asset-pipeline-gradle/src/main/groovy/asset/pipeline/gradle/AssetPipelinePlugin.groovy#L91)

Comment: Thanks for answer. I think it might be wort mentioning that explicitly in Grails migration guide.

Comment: Do you have any example of how to write such a plugin? I cannot find it anywhere.